# fastest way to read raw data from interface c++

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, packet-capture

Here is the main problem.

1. I have 10-gigabit ethernet interface and current flow is 6-7 Gbit/sec
2. I need to implement a firewall Then I need to capture raw packets to filter some packets.
3. Simply I started to implement as a raw socket necessary codes are at below. Socket bound to a specific interface.

   ```
   socketfd=socket(AF_PACKET,SOCK_RAW,htons(ETH_P_ALL));
   strncpy(ifopts.ifr_name,interfaceName,IFNAMSIZ-1);
   ioctl(socketfd,SIOCGIFINDEX,&ifopts);
   sll.sll_family=AF_INET;
   sll.sll_ifindex=ifopts.ifr_ifindex;
   sll.sll_protocol=htons(ETH_PALL);
   bind(socketfd,&sll,sizeof(sll));
   ```
4. Here is how I read and mtu size is 9000

   ```
   while(true)
   recvfrom(socketfd,buffer,9000,0,0,0);
   ```
5. Without any process on a packet I got ~150Mbit/sec.

This is the problem I need to solve. I realize that nload or ip -s link shows the actual rate; but I cannot reach these numbers around 6-7Gbit/sec.

~150Mbit/sec is so ridiculous rate for me. I need to increase performance as much as I can do using one CPU. I will try to use PF_INET, if you want I can share the result of it.

Comment: On sending side you reach these rates?

Comment: Sending side is the local network, so more than one pc generates this rate. I can simply monitor using nload how much data flows. It is around 6-7 Gbit/sec

Comment: The system like this
Internet <-------->firewall (actually me)<------------->local network

Comment: Update: If I use libpcap, I can capture up to 3-4 Gbit/sec

Comment: PF_RING is the solution, I can get up to 10 Gbit/sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

- First of all capturing speed is not only depend on the size of bytes on the interface, but the number of packets is also important. So socket programming is also limited by the number of packets. I measured as 200k packets per second (pps).
- Using better network driver is the one way of the increasing pps. PF_RING is the possible library and driver. You may use the trial version to test. I simply test it on my network and result is 14M pps. Then this rate is almost 10Gbit/sec. That's all I experienced.

Thanks all.